# Why does VSCode C++ yield 'explicit type is missing' warning for templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have the following code

```
using namespace std;

template <class T>
vector<T> func(){
    return vector<T>(100,0);
}

int main(){
    auto test = func<int>();
    cout << test[0] << " " << test.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without warning and runs correctly, but VSCode intelisense highlights `test` with the warning `explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)`. Am I doing something wrong here? Changing the line to `vector<int> test = func<int>();` makes VSCode happy, but I don't see why there would be any issue with auto here. Am I missing something?

The only fix VSCode offers is to disable error squiggles, which I like in other instances.

Comment: Your intelisense doesn't know what C++ standard you are building against. `auto` as a placeholder type is only C++11 and later. So you should configure the VSCode extension responsible.

Comment: This worked, for anyone else who has this issue, note that VSCode had to be closed for the changes to take effect.

Comment: @eeegnu Feel free to post an answer explaining in detail how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language version needed to be configured correctly. To resolve this I followed the configuration steps here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_cc-configurations

I ended up with the following global `settings.json`

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\...\\g++.exe"
}
```

Then after restarting VSCode it worked!